# How to change python version in windows git bash?

Tags: python, git-bash

I've installed python 3.5 and python 2.7 on windows. And I've added path for python 2.7 in PATH variable. When I type 'python --version' in windows cmd, it prints 2.7. But when i type 'python --version' in git bush, it prints 3.5.
How to change python version in windows git bash to 2.7?

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Git bash, `cd ~`
2. Depending on your favorite editor`touch`, `code` or `vim` (in my case) type `code .bashrc`
3. Add the line `alias python='winpty c:/Python27/python.exe'` to the open .bashrc
4. Save and Close.
5. Try `python --version` on git bash again.

Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the path inside git bash to the correct folder.

Example:

```
PATH=$PATH:/c/Python27/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me on Windows 10 (a modified version of Job Collins answer):

1. Edit .bashrc file or create it at the user home if does not exist:

```
    cd ~
    nano .bashrc
```

2. add this line (modify the user name and the python version part, the apostrophe and quotes are important)

```
     alias python='winpty "C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"'
```

3. activate

```
source .bashrc
```

4. check if everything is ok

```
python --version
```